# How to compare two screen shots in sikuli and verify whether they are same?

Tags: automation, sikuli

I have two screenshots which I need to verify whether they are the same or not using sikuli - can we do that?

If yes - then how?

Comment: Check this if it helps https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/121303 and  https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2459/compare-screenshots-of-rendered-web-pages

Comment: How are you using Sikuli? Through IDE? Python? Java?

Answer (score 0):

principally (supposing both shots are the same size):

```
finder = Finder(shot1)
finder.find(shot2)
if finder.hasNext():
  print "equal"
else:
  print "different"
```